# How does dimension work in Fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran, declare

I don't get why

```
IMPLICIT REAL*8(A-Z)
DIMENSION A(20)
```

compiles fine, and

```
REAL*8, DIMENSION A(20)
```

results in error

> Missing dimension specification at ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are two different meanings of `dimension`.  The first is a `dimension` statement and the second you mean to specify the `dimension` attribute in a declaration.

In a declaration where attributes are specified it is necessary to have `::`:

```
REAL*8, DIMENSION(20) :: A
```

Note also that the array specification comes attached to the `dimension`, not to the variable name.

Use of `::` is merely optional in a `dimension` statement (except in Fortran 77 where it wasn't allowed).

However, it is simply allowed to write

```
real*8 A(20)
```

as the `dimension` attribute is also specified by giving the array specification.

---

It's possibly also worth noting that, as the declaration line in the question is incorrect, that in fixed-form source the mistake is different.

In fixed-form source, spaces are not of note (beyond the column layout), so

```
      real*8, dimension a(20)
```

is the statement

```
      real*8 dimensiona(20)
```

with an extraneous comma.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

```
IMPLICIT REAL*8(A-Z)
DIMENSION A(20)
```

is the array statement declaration introduced in earlier versions of fortran (see [this link for example](https://www.fortran.com/F77_std/rjcnf-8.html)), and it works that way.

```
REAL*8, DIMENSION A(20)
```

is not f77, nor f90 or other. Fortran 90 and above uses this

```
REAL*8, DIMENSION(20) :: A
```

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, details are important though, I sometime forget to pay attention, but I should. The comment of francescalus (that he deletes already) actually reminds me that I had never paid any attention to fortran 66. I almost never think about it unless I am teaching the history of programming languages and then I have no choice of saying a word. I was introduced to fortran 77, and I never went below.